# tensorflow GPU training doesn't take place

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, loss

I am using the following code (once on CPU (without the "disable_eager_execution" part)) and yet once more with GPU.

On the CPU training, one epoch takes 12 Hours but the loss changes from batch to batch and I see that training takes place.

On the GPU version. Nothing happens. Training one epoch takes around 1 Hour but loss and accuracy stay the same.

PLEASE HELP ME UNDERSTAND WHAT DO I DO WRONG...

I am running this code using aws sage maker (ml.g4dn.4xlarge)

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import datetime
import tensorflow as tf
import re
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution

print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')), '\n')
disable_eager_execution()

# Read data

# read dictionaries:
# company_dict:
company_df = pd.read_csv("/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/company_similarity/data/company_dict.csv", sep='\t', header=None)
company_df.columns = ['company_id', 'idx']

# payee dict
payee_df = pd.read_csv("/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/company_similarity/data/cleaned_up_payee_dict.csv", sep='\t', header=None)
payee_df.columns = ['payee', 'idx']



# Read raw data
BATCH_SIZE = 32
raw_data = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    "/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/company_similarity/data/training_data.csv",
    column_names=['company_id', 'payee', 'label'],
    select_columns=['company_id', 'payee', 'label'],
    field_delim='\t',
    column_defaults=[tf.string, tf.string, tf.int32],
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    label_name='label',
    na_value="?",
    num_epochs=1,
    ignore_errors=True,
)


class PreprocessingFeatures(object):
    def __init__(self, company_idx, payee_idx):
        self.payee_idx = payee_idx
        self.company_idx = company_idx
        self.symbols = '!"$%&\'\?()*+,-./:;<=>?[\\]^_`{|}~a-zA-Z0-9 '
        self.payee_lookup = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup(vocabulary=payee_idx,
                                                                                    mask_token=None,
                                                                                    num_oov_indices=1
                                                                                   )
        self.company_lookup = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.StringLookup(vocabulary=company_idx,
                                                                                      mask_token=None,
                                                                                      num_oov_indices=1
                                                                                      )

    def __call__(self, features, labels):
        payee = self.payee_lookup(features['payee'])
        company = self.company_lookup(features['company_id'])
        return (company, payee), labels


payee_list = list(payee_df['payee'])
company_list = [str(si) for si in list(company_df['company_id'])]


# ************ START TRAINING ************ #


log_dir = '/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/company_similarity/models/logs/fit/' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
checkpoint_dir = '/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/company_similarity/models/embedding_checkpoints'
file_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_dir + "/metrics")
file_writer.set_as_default()


def present_topK(model, listA, item_title='eBay', topK=10):
    '''
    show top 10 similar items using model embedding
    :param model: the actual model
    :param item_index: dictionary with item name:index format
    :param index_item: dictionary with index:item name format
    :param item_title: title text
    :return: table to print (string)
    '''
    assert item_title in listA, "Item not in Vocabulary"
    emb = model.layers[2].get_weights()[0]
    # we started from 1 not zero on dictionary
    score = cosine_similarity(emb[listA.index(item_title)+1].reshape(1, -1), emb)[0]
    similar_items = np.argsort(score)[::-1][:topK]
    res = {'payee': [], 'score': []}
    for i in similar_items:
        res['payee'] += [listA[i-1]]
        res['score'] += [score[i]]

    return "\n".join("{}\t{}".format(k, v) for k, v in res.items())


class GenerateExamplesCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def __init__(self):
        self.step = 0

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.step += 1
        self.model.save('/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/company_similarity/models/embedding_checkpoints/model_{}'.format(epoch))
        sim_table = present_topK(self.model, payee_list)
        print("\nSimilar Items to 'eBay': ", sim_table)
        with file_writer.as_default():
            tf.summary.text('Similarity sanity check', data=tf.convert_to_tensor(sim_table), step=epoch)

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        if batch % 1000 == 0:
            sim_table = present_topK(self.model, payee_list)
            print("\nSimilar Items to 'eBay': ", sim_table)
            with file_writer.as_default():
                tf.summary.text('Similarity sanity check', data=tf.convert_to_tensor(sim_table), step=batch)


print('TensorBoard logging folder: ', log_dir)
print("checkpoint_dir:", checkpoint_dir)

checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt_{epoch}")
checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_prefix, save_weights_only=True, save_freq=200000)
early_stopping_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=2)
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1, update_freq=10000)
callbacks = [checkpoint_callback, tensorboard_callback, GenerateExamplesCallback()]

# read the data
# train_data = raw_data.map(PreprocessingFeatures(company_list, payee_list)).shuffle(buffer_size=10000).repeat()
train_data = raw_data.map(PreprocessingFeatures(company_list, payee_list)).repeat()

# examples
# next(iter(raw_data.take(1)))
# next(iter(train_data))

# wc -l <filename> on terminal
fileLen = 5851184
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = (fileLen // BATCH_SIZE) + 1
# STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 1000

def build_model(company_embedding=128, payee_embedding=128, loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy):
    company_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(name='company_input', shape=(1,))
    payee_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(name='payee_input', shape=(1,))
    company_emb = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(name='company_embedding',
                                            input_dim=len(company_list)+1,
                                            output_dim=company_embedding)(company_input)
    company_emb = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(company_emb)
    payee_emb = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(name='payee_embedding',
                                          input_dim=len(payee_list)+1,
                                          output_dim=payee_embedding)(payee_input)
    payee_emb = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(payee_emb)
    merged = tf.keras.layers.Dot(name='dot', normalize=True, axes=1)([payee_emb, company_emb])
    merged = tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape = [1])(merged)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged)

    # x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([item_emb, device_emb])
    # x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    # x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    # x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    # x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    # x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
    # # x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    # x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=(company_input, payee_input), outputs=x)

    model.compile(
        loss=loss,
        optimizer='adam',
        metrics=['accuracy'],
    )

    return model

model = build_model()

EPOCHS = 5

r = model.fit(train_data,
              epochs=EPOCHS,
              steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
              callbacks=callbacks
              )

model.save("/home/ec2user/SageMaker/company_similarity/models/models/embedding_model_final.h5")

print("Training is completed")
```

Comment: what tensorflow version do you use? What CUDA version?